# How to force Cloudfront to make all requests from origin forced to be HTTPS?

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-lightsail

I am having some odd behavior with my Cloudfront distribution for my website https://phillhocking.com

This Cloudfront distribution is managed by Terraform, and here is the code I am using to instantiate it:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "ghost-lightsail" {
  price_class = "PriceClass_100"

  origin {
    domain_name = var.cloudfront_glue
    origin_id   = "${var.name}-origin"

    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = 80
      https_port             = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  default_root_object = "/"

  #  lifecycle {
  #    prevent_destroy = true
  #  }

  aliases = [var.domain_name]

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.name}-origin"
    compress         = true

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      headers      = ["*"]

      cookies {
        forward = "all"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "assets/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.name}-origin"
    compress         = true

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      headers      = ["*"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "content/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.name}-origin"
    compress         = true

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      headers      = ["*"]
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "public/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.name}-origin"
    compress         = true

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "img_responsive/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.name}-origin"
    compress         = true

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.name}-dev"
  }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn      = var.cloudfront_ssl_acm_arn
    ssl_support_method       = "sni-only"
    minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.1_2016"
  }
}
```

The entire project is located here: https://github.com/phillhocking/aws-ghost/tree/dev

You will note that `redirect-to-https` is true for all of the content types, however, it still tries to load content via http for any images on the Lightsail instance that are *new* posts and I am not sure how to diagnose/troubleshoot this any further. My goal is to not have to do any systems administration tasks on the Lightsail instance and fix this via the Cloudfront distribution.

This only happens with a particular post: https://phillhocking.com/new-linkedin-feature-request/

[Note the content from the CDN distribution is requesting an http:// image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9x89.png)

When you click on these links in the Developer pane, it goes to the image without any issue. Why would the Cloudfront distribution not automatically manage this behavior from the origin?

Comment: Oh I just noticed that on other pages it has the same issue, but Chrome (Chromium) "automatically upgrades the request" to https:// which I don't know why it wouldn't happen on the other post.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection works correctly. You can't fetch your images with http, only https. But this will only take effect when you will actually try get the images.

I think that chrome just checks the source code of your page, and sees http  for images or some of the links, and stops. It does not try to actually fetch the images and follow redirection from http to https.

Comment: Hey, @Marcin , thank you for your reply. I am noticing that it actually is 'automatically upgrading' certain images to https:// e.g. https://phillhocking.com/deploying-salt-minion-on-windows/

Isn't there a way to force the Cloudfront distribution to serve these as https:// without having to touch the origin to make a rewrite rule? The Bitnami container is so complicated that every time I touch it - it just redirects everything causing "too many redirects."

Comment: Here is an example of this behavior of "automatically upgrading to https": https://imgur.com/a/d6v8Rdw

Comment: @phillhocking I don't know. Usually you would fix your website, and change its source code to use https. If its wordpress, maybe there is an easy way for that?

Comment: its a Bitnami Lightsail appliance, and it seems like they have it set up to handle http/https itself, and it seems to introduce this fault when you try to set the http appliance to have an https prefix, really frustrating: https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-aws-ghost-appliance-behind-cloudfront-ghost-config-url-directive-redirects-to-127-0-0-1/96668